# Call Template inside preceding-sibling

Tags: xslt, node-set

I am a pretty newbie to XSLT (using XSLT 1.0).
Couple of questions:

1. I am currently working on a scenario which requires me to invoke a call
   template from inside a preceding-sibling iteration Is there a way to
   achieve this?
2. How can I convert a Result tree fragment to node-set?

Example: 
*`<xsl:variable name="node-set" select="msxml:node-set($result-tree-fragment-variable)">`*

Upon debugging $node-set, I still see tree fragment and not a node-set

Please guide me.

Comment: Show your input and output XML and enough standalone XSLT to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: As for the debugging problem, you will need to share which tool/debugger you use. If the `msxml:node-set` function is supported by your XSLT processor and you have the right namespace, then your snippet looks fine.

Comment: Thanks guys, my problem is solved. Everything looks good, my debugger tricked me displaying the tree fragment format even though it's a node set in the quick watch. Restarting visual studio (after 24 days) helped me.